# What is best way access different database on different engine but with similar structure

Tags: c#, database, linq

I usually work with MySql, but also with SQL Server, Oracle and Access, the database structure is almost the same. My database stores configuration and recorded data of a SCADA application ("Supervisory Control And Data Acquisition").
Most of the tables are usually the same but sometime my teammates adds fields, tables or changes some fields type.

I'm writing an application that need to load some config parameters from db, then load data, process it and store the new values on db. It also need to add new records.

I have a class that, independently from db type, given the correct connection params, gets a `IDbConnection` object. With some methods I can specified a SQL query and it give me and `IDataReader` or a also `Dataset`.

Now, how should i query data from the db, analyze, recalculate, and finally store them again?
I'm a bit scared of building a detailed object mapping because of the possibility of changed fields. A simple dataset/datatable/datarow should be ok but i'd like to use linq to query in a simpler way the extracted data from the database.

Finally, my db has about 60 tables but in this application I work only with a dozen of them. I have only a few time to build that application, so I need a fast way, also if it's not "very beautiful".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should try an ORM that configures itself automatically according to schema

i have found this one. I didn't use similar things in c# but it works nicely in other (dynamic) languages.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117666/Kerosene-ORM

Answer (score 0):

Using an ORM would most probably be the fastest. You could use [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) which has [multiple DB support](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasesSupportedByNHibernate?_sscc=t). NHibernate does have a learning curve, so something like a micro ORM could be easier to use perhaps. [Petapoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) is a great micro ORM and supports SQL Server, SQL Server CE, MySQL, PostgreSQL and Oracle.

These ORMs would create a mapping file for each DB you use which needs to be updated or recreated when changes are made in the DB.

Comment: Thanks @Ewald Stieger but with this ORM I have to manually create all the classes corresponding to my database tables? It's correct?

Comment: @Pomp No, the ORM will create the classes automatically, e.g. with Petapoco you just specifiy the connection string and run the T4 template to create all the DB classes.